# AJAX Cookie not saving to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, cookies

Okay. So relevant code first:

jQuery:

```
saveFilterCookie: function( obj ) {
    $.ajax( {
        url     : saveFilterCookie,
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : { filter: obj },
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function( data, status, jqxhr)
        {
            var headers = jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()
            console.log(headers);
        },
        error    : function( jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown )
        {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
},
```

PHP:

```
public function saveFilterAction( ) {

    $filter = $this->request->get( 'filter', null );

    // Expiration days
    $expirationDays = $this->serviceContainer->getParameter( 'filter_cookie_expiration_days' );

    // Cookie expiration time
    $expirationTime = time() + ( 3600 * 24 * $expirationDays );

    // Set filter cookie
    $this->response->headers->setCookie( new Cookie( '_filter', $filter, $expirationTime ) );

    return $this->renderJSON( json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) ) );
}
```

I get an appropriate response from the AJAX call. Status 200, everything looks good. The cookie is even in the response headers (according to Google Chrome's inspector). But then when I navigate to the next page, the cookie is magically gone.

Response in Inspector:

[image: Inspector Headers]

Any thoughts? I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious.

**EDIT: Solution**

For those interested, this problem was solved by simply creating the cookie client side, since going to the server and back was not needed. See [W3 Schools article on JS Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for details.

Comment: Path should be defaulting to "/". Appears to be what it's doing by the header response. Will edit to add response image.

Comment: What is the difference in url from this page to the next? Also why set the cookie on the sever?

Comment: Honestly I didn't even consider setting the cookie client side. Thanks @mplungjan. That'll solve this one.

Comment: Great. Delete or rewrite the question if you have the same issue client-side. For example if you go from http to https or similar